# gitignore does not exclude vcs.xml but works on others

Tags: git, gitignore

My .gitignore file does not exclude vcs.xml but works on others

Here is my .gitignore :

```
#################
## Pycharm
#################
.idea
.idea/*.xml
.idea/*
*/.idea/*
```

The rest of the files in the .idea folder are excluded, but `vcs.xml` does not obey the `.idea/*.xml` rule:
[image: github]

I have tried:

- using the right menu option to exclude [image: github menu]
- excluding the folder entirely .idea/*
- excluding all file under folder .idea
- restarting GitHub desktop
- restarting the computer

[image: gitignore]

Comment: If the file is tracked already, .gitignore won't hold water if you want to _not_ track it anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)